# Ios devices, "required" field and thank you message

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, required, requiredfieldvalidator

I would like to merge two JavaScripts. The first one is using ajax to send message and the second one to alert user about required field in the contact form.

I want to merge this two, maybe with an IF statement, so first to check all fields and then to send message.

1 with ajax JavaScript:

```
    $('document').ready(function () {
    $('form#contact-form').submit(function () {
        var form = $(this);
        var post_data = form.serialize(); //Serialized the form data for process.php
        $('#loader').html('<img src="../spinner.gif" /> Please Wait...');

        form.fadeOut(500, function () {
            form.html("<h3>Thank you.").fadeIn();
            $('#loader').html('');
        });

        // Normally would use this
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php', // Your form script
            data: post_data,
            success: function(msg) {
                form.fadeOut(500, function(){
                    form.html(msg).fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

2 alert JavaScript:

```
 $('document').ready(function () {
    $('form#contact-form').submit(function(e) {

        var ref = $(this).find("[required]");

        $(ref).each(function(){
            if ( $(this).val() == '' )
            {
                alert("Required field should not be blank.");

                $(this).focus();

                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });  return true;
    });
});
```

From the answer below i have create the following code.

I made this link if someone wants to help. The alert works fine but the code not stop. It continue to load the rest code.

https://jsfiddle.net/L8huq1t1/

Comment: Why do you want to merge code? Think aboout single responsibility.

Comment: Do you use jquery.validate file or you want your custom validation?

Comment: It is a contact form. My problem is that in Ios, the required field is not working. With this javascript, i manage to alert the users.

Comment: @Yvette, have you checked my solution?!

Comment: @Ionut Your solution is not working. Maybe there is a mistake  ;)

Comment: @KinjalMistry A custom validate is better. I want my webpage light weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by the following code.

```
function checkValidation() {
        var ref = $(this).find("[required]");
        $(ref).each(function(){
            if ( $(this).val() == '' )
            {
                alert("Required field should not be blank.");
                $(this).focus();
                //e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('form#contact-form').submit(function () {
        if(!checkValidation()) {
            return false;
        }

        var form = $(this);
        var post_data = form.serialize(); //Serialized the form data for process.php
        $('#loader').html('<img src="../spinner.gif" /> Please Wait...');

        form.fadeOut(500, function () {
            form.html("<h3>Thank you.").fadeIn();
            $('#loader').html('');
        });

        // Normally would use this
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php', // Your form script
            data: post_data,
            success: function(msg) {
                form.fadeOut(500, function(){
                    form.html(msg).fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

But I give you a suggestion to use jquery.validate plugin which is better option. But if you still want to do like this, go ahead this is also works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested your code but in ios is not working!!! I found a small mistake 
//e.preventDefault(); 
and correct it 
e.preventDefault(); I will try it again to see.

Comment: Your code is easier to understand but i can't find where it is wrong. On Ios devices it seems like the function is not working.

Comment: @Yvette What problem exactly you face in IOS?

Comment: The function checkValidation is not working. I change your code with no function, and it works. But i haven't manage to make it work 100%... It shows the validate alert and then it continue to load the ajax. See my code above. I am missing something small to make it work.

Comment: @Yvette try to uncomment 'e.preventDefault();'

Comment: Tried it. No luck. See my last code in my first post.

Comment: can you give me your PC on remote? so will check the exact issue what you face?

Comment: If you load  jsfiddle.net/L8huq1t1 on ios device and leave all "required" fields empty, you will alert but you will also see the "Thank you" message. On desktop the code works fine because "required" is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Validation plugin that has a form submit handler where you can put your AJAX. [Link to the plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Your code should look something like this:

```js
$('#contact-form').validate({
  rules: {
    your_input_name: {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    your_input_name: {
      required: 'Field is required'
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function() {
    var form = $(this);
    var post_data = form.serialize(); //Serialized the form data for process.php
    $('#loader').html('<img src="../spinner.gif" /> Please Wait...');

    form.fadeOut(500, function() {
      form.html("<h3>Thank you.").fadeIn();
      $('#loader').html('');
    });

    // Normally would use this
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'process.php', // Your form script
      data: post_data,
      success: function(msg) {
        form.fadeOut(500, function() {
          form.html(msg).fadeIn();
        });
      }
    });

    return false;
  }
});
```